# Copy news templates to multiple sites

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to copy news templates from one modern site to many others, automatically. I soon realized that the template newspages is stored in Sitepages/Templates on a site.

Using PNP Copy file I can copy the template files to any site I want:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/DevTemplate"
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl "Sitepages/Templates" -TargetUrl "/sites/Dev_Test21/Sitepages" -OverwriteIfAlreadyExists -Force
```

Now to the issue, when I copy the files to a new site with newsfeed, I cannot use the template pages that I copy. They just wont show up even if the Template folder is there with items in it.[image]

If I then manually creates ONE template ("ik" on pic below), the copied files also shows because they are in the Sitepages/templates already. It's like I need to create one manually to enable the template function at all.

Any ideas or anyone who managed to copy Sharepoint news templates between sites?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, it's the same behavior with you, I think this is by design.

It's necessary to have at least one page template in the target site first.